# Is there a way to open a webdriver tab with selenium without opening the webdriver window?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was recently experimenting with Selenium in Python and noticed that every time I created a new webdriver object and used `webdriver.get(website)`, the webdriver window would open first (black window that sort of looks like the terminal) and then the actual tab with the website would open.  Is there anyway to run the webdriver in the background so only the tab opens without the webdriver window opening?

EDIT: Currently using the Chrome webdriver.

Answer (score 1):

to make chrome run in background you can add `headless mode` option

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')

print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```